# facing Java multithread concurrency issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have created three thread like client1, client2, client3 with corresponding read request "read 2", "read 1", "read 3". i wanted to process a read request in following manner:

Client2 read 1

Client1 read 2

Client3 read 3

i don't have idea to run a thread (client2) first and then thread (client1) and so on based on read request sequence.There is a one condition that i can't use sleep in my program.

Please provide help in above context of problem if anyone know about the solution.

Comment: Basically, you want sequential behavior come out of multiple threads. That's backwards to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your program, it could be done using 2 [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to synchronize your threads, one to release `Client1` once `Client2` has done reading and another one to release `Client3` once `Client1` has done reading.

```
// Used to release client1 
CountDownLatch startThread1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
Thread client2 = new Thread(
    () -> {
        System.out.println("Read 1");
        // Release client1
        startThread1.countDown();
    }
);
// Used to release client3
CountDownLatch startThread3 = new CountDownLatch(1);
Thread client1 = new Thread(
    () -> {
        try {
            // Waiting to be released
            startThread1.await();
            System.out.println("Read 2");
            // Release client3
            startThread3.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
);
Thread client3 = new Thread(
    () -> {
        try {
            // Waiting to be released
            startThread3.await();
            System.out.println("Read 3");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
);
// Start the threads in reverse order intentionally to show that 
// we still have the expected order
client3.start();
client1.start();
client2.start();
```

**Output:**

```
Read 1
Read 2
Read 3
```

This approach guarantees to get the correct read sequence whatever the order of the start sequence of your threads.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solutions. it was really helpful to solve my problem